# PHP how to get facebook profile name

Tags: php, facebook

```
function getTitle($Url)
{
    $str = file_get_contents($Url);

    if(strlen($str)>0)
    {
        preg_match("/\<title(.*)\<\/title\>/",$str,$title);

        if(empty($title))
        {
            $dom = new DOMDocument();
            @$dom->loadHTML($str);

            $title = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title');

            if(empty($title->item(0)->nodeValue))
                return "";
            else
                return $title->item(0)->nodeValue;
        }
        else
            return $title[1];
    }
}
```

I used two ways to get the title tags of facebook but it not working. The facebook site reading info from my site host but I want it to read from user's browser
I need any way to read the title tags

```
 <title> ..... </title>
```

of the facebook site. If I logged in the facebook site the title tags will be

```
<title id="pageTitle">Facebook</title>
```

Comment: You can't use PHP to read a page from the user's browser. What you want to do is likely impossible - for good reason.

Comment: but it works with say the code getTitle(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AB-1HhUg0GU) the result is "LIONEL RICHIE   HELLOW‬‏ - YouTube"

Comment: Yes, because YouTube serves that title to *everyone.*

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side programming language, so you can not read from user browser directly. For server side your function may work or try this one that it been tested for you :

```
$myURL = 'http://www.google.com';
if (preg_match(
        '/<title>(.+)<\/title>/',
        file_get_contents($myURL),$matches) 
    && isset($matches[1] )
   $title = $matches[1];
else
   $title = "Not Found";
```

Comment: thanks  Kamal AL-Hinai, but I want to do it exactly on facebook. It may work with google and youtube but not with facebook. So the solution will be using JavaScript I hope it works well.